# Understanding the link between phase noise and line width, and phase noise units (in the context of optical physics / lasers)

Tags: optics, laser

Trying to understand the phase noise units, and what they mean / how to convert between them.

For instance, [dBc/Hz --> dB(rad/sqrt(Hz))]?

But also, linewidth measurements are often given for a variety of different integration bandwidths, but the choices seem very arbitrary, and I really don't get why or where they come from, and to be honest, linewidth seems like a terrible measurement and I don't understand the purpose it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spectrum of anything is a "power" spectrum because these are the Fourier Transforms of mean square averages and correlations, etc. When calculating the phase noise spectrum of an oscillator it is usually assumed that the amplitude oscillation is negligible, so that the oscillator signal is modeled as $\underline{X} (t) = A \rm{cos}(\omega_0 t +  \underline{\Phi})$ with a constant $A$ amplitude and the underline "$\underline{}$" designates a stochastic variable.

For *small* phase error $\underline{\Phi}$, 
$\rm{cos}(\underline{\Phi}) \approx 1$ and $\rm{sin}(\underline{\Phi}) \approx \underline{\Phi} $, so one can write 
$$\underline{X} (t) = A \rm{cos}(\omega_0 t +  \underline{\Phi})
= A\rm{cos}(\omega_0 t) cos(\underline{\Phi}) - A\rm{sin}(\omega_0 t) sin(\underline{\Phi}))\\
\approx A\rm{cos}(\omega_0 t) - A\underline{\Phi}\rm{sin}(\omega_0 t)$$

This has two terms both being proportional to $A$. The 1st term is the "noiseless carrier", is pure sinusoid of power $\frac{1}{2} A^2$, the 2nd term, whose "sin" carrier is in quadrature with the "cos" carrier, has a spectrum that is proportional to the spectrum of the phase noise $\underline{\Phi}$.

Let the spectrum of a stochastic process $\underline{Z}$ be $S_Z(u)$ where $u$ is the spectral frequency, then the spectrum of $\rm{cos}(\omega_0 t)$ is the discrete  term $\delta(u-\omega_0)+\delta(\omega_0+u)$ and the continuous term will be $S_{\Phi}(u-\omega_0)+S_{\Phi}(\omega_0+u)$, thus

$$S_X(u) \approx  A^2(\delta(u-\omega_0)+\delta(\omega_0+u)) + A^2(S_{\Phi}(u-\omega_0)+S_{\Phi}(\omega_0+u))$$

With the small phase noise approximation $S_X(u)$ can be measured by a narrow  bandpass (IF) filter and power detector. Center the filter at $\omega_1$ and let its transfer function and bandwidth be $H(\omega)$ and $B$ such that $B<< \omega_0$. Then after much averaging ("video" filter) one can show that the power $p(\omega_1)$ measured at the filter output is approximately
$$p(\omega_1) \approx |H(\omega_1)|^2 S_X(\omega_1) B$$

Notice that since both discrete and continuous parts are proportional to $A^2$ thus the "relative" noisiness of the signal, ie., phase noise *density* power relative to the carrier power is independent of the latter.
After scanning the filter center frequency $\omega_1$ in the range of interest you can map the spectrum $S_X(u)$ so if the latter is normalized to the total signal power $A^2$ you get the power spectrum density of the phase noise $\underline{\Phi}$. The former has units $\rm{watts/Hz}$ since it is power measured per unit bandwidth of the filter, while the latter being normalized to the power has units $\rm{Hz}^{-1}$ or since it represents "phase" its unit is $\rm{rad}^2/Hz$ representing the mean square phase fluctuation measured after the narrowband filter. If you rather deal with standard deviation (root mean square deviation) rather than with variance (mean square deviation) then yur units will be $\rm{rad/\sqrt{Hz}}$ instead of $\rm{rad^2/Hz}$.

(The "dBc" thing is just an indication that the result of the power measurement is given in logarithmically (decibel) relative to the total carrier power, the "c".)

Comment: I think I understand all of this, at least up until the 2nd to last paragraph. By normalizing to the total signal power - measured in watts - you can remove the watts/Hz, which just leaves you with inverse Hertz. I don't understand where the square radian comes from. Normalization would just be a simple division, and its not like dividing by watts will give you square radians.

Comment: the units $rad^2/Hz$ or sometime s written in $deg^2/Hz$ when multiplied by $(180/pi)^2$ are the units of $\Phi^2/B$ whose average is the "power" content of the phase noise per unit bandwidth. This is what you have when you normalize to (divide by) $A^2$ the power measured at the spectrum scanning (tunable) filter output whose bandwidth is $B$.

Comment: if you integrate the area under the continuous part of the spectrum then you get the total mean square phase fluctuation whose units are $rad^2$ or $deg^2$

Comment: Hmm... Okay, I thought I understood after the first comment, but the second confused me a bit more. I thought that the linewidth was the integrated area under the curve for phase noise, which should be in units Hertz.

Comment: The power and power spectrum of $A\Phi$ has units $watts\cdot rad^2$ and $watts\cdot rad^2/Hz$, resp. If you integrate the latter over all frequencies you get the former that is the total power. If you remove $A$ (divide with it) you get the total "power" of the phase noise that is just another word for the total mean square phase noise (fluctuation). The "signal" is in the $Acos(\omega_0 t)$ term whose power is $A^2$ (or rather $A^2/2$) with which the measured filter output power is proportional.

Comment: I see. So to convert from phase noise to line width, for instance, I need to take a SSB phase noise measurement on an ESA, convert into dBc/Hz by normalizing to power A, and the bandwidth B [already done for me on my particular ESA], then I convert this phase noise into frequency noise via (S_{f} = f^2 * S_{phi}), Then I just integrate that frequency noise over some bounds f_1 to f_2, and take the square root, and what I'm left with is linewidth.

Comment: I have avoided answering your question directly regarding the term "linewidth" for I do not know of a *mathematical* definition for it. In spectrum analysis practice the IF *resolution bandwidth* (RBW) should be wide enough around $\omega_0$ to capture not just a *stationary* $\rm{cos}(\omega_0 t)$ but also if it is pulsed or slowly modulated and then the smallest *practical* such RBW is essentially an estimate of linewidth but this is a bit hokey. In real life, $\omega_0$ always varies slowly in time, temperature, pressure, humidity, power supply, so RBW must be wide enough to cover those.